# If correlation is not causation how do we establish causality?

Tags: discussion

Can causality be established?

If causality cannot be established, then how do we know what causes what?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correlation has to do with it. I mean, a banana is also not causation, but why not ask about how we establish causations if it is not a banana? So the real question should be: "how to establish causality". The answer would probably be "hypothesise, do a scientific test, conclude, peer review, publish, repeat"

Comment: @Nanne: Because we are frequently warned (and/or frequently warn others) that correlation is not to be confused with causation.

Comment: But if you accept that this is the case, it is completely another topic. If you don't accept it, this question is actually about doubting the non-equality of the two. In the first case, you don't need to specify it for the question, in the second case this is a completely different question. I know we are talking about this a lot, but I don't see why it matters when talking about causality.

Answer (score 2):

This is a topic that has been widely covered by others.

Here are just some:

- https://explorable.com/cause-and-effect
- http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/causeeff.php
- http://briandusbiber.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/establishing-causality-in-research-analysis-pitfalls-and-issues/
- http://www.stats.org/faq_vs.htm
- http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/if-correlation-doesnt-imply-causation-then-what-does/

They tend to define a number of conditions (e.g. temporal association, exclusion of other explanations) and point out how well-chosen control groups can be used to establish causality.

Comment: And my favourite: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYPapE-3FRw

Comment: You should probably give the cliff notes of some of the links you are referring to. Right now your answer in itself is only a collection of links and not an actual answer.

Comment: @Alexandre: I had hoped the last sentence covered that.